# Changing record type LABEL

Tags: record-type, label

I would like to double check with you experts. I want to change the Record type label in one of my objects. Nothing should be impacted since the RecordtypeDeveloperName is not changed right?

Comment: check where used as filter criteria in reports and listviews too

Answer (score 3):

"Nothing" is a pretty big statement. It is certainly possible for a change in a Record Type Label to cause issues.

For example, in older code that predates [`getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm), and even in some code that postdates it but uses older practices, it's common to access Record Types by label in Apex code.

This change should certainly be vetted in a sandbox with a full Apex test run, but the specific customizations you have may demand a full regression testing process. (For example, integrations might consume the label as well).

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if there are any references to the record type label in apex classes, formulas and criteria (workflows, flows, sharing rules). It's good practice to reference the developer name in those scenarios, but there's no guarantee that the label hasn't been used instead.

A scan through metadata for "RecordType.Name" will give you an indication of what could be impacted if you change the label.